# vb .net override subclass method of inherited base class

Tags: .net, vb.net, inheritance

I'm trying to create a "prototype" class for a specific WPF-control (Autodesk's Ribbontextbox - based on WPF Textbox), which includes it's own commandhandler class.

The RibbonTextBox is intended to use the ICommand Interface for actions, rather then Event System, meaning it has a Commandhandler Property which I can assign a Command to...
My thought is to create a base class, including it's own Command-Class, so in the  derived one I just need to override the execute method.

```
mustinherit class BaseClass
      inherits RibbonTextBox
sub new()    
    me.Commandhandler= New CommandBase
end sub 

public Class CommandBase
           implements ICommand
       Protected Overridable Function CanExecute(parameter As Object) As Boolean Implements System.Windows.Input.ICommand.CanExecute
        Return Not parameter.value.ToString.IsEmptyStringOrNothing
    End Function

    Public Event CanExecuteChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Implements System.Windows.Input.ICommand.CanExecuteChanged

    Protected Overridable Sub Execute(parameter As Object) Implements System.Windows.Input.ICommand.Execute
'This Method should be defined in the derived Instance!!!
    End Sub

end class
```

How I'd like to use this:

```
public Class DerivedClass
            inherits BaseClass

public Overrides sub me.commandhandler.Execute() 'or some similar :-)
'here the definition of commandexecution
end sub 

end Class
```

any hints were appreciated!
Thanks,
D

Comment: I think you'll have to use event/delegate, your DerivedClass would have to handle a ExecuteEvent. An other option would be to have a DerivedCommandClass that derive from CommandBase and take a DerivedClass a parameter to it's constructor.

Comment: I was afraid so :-( I wanted to avoid some Eventhandling overhead....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override from an other class that way. If you don't want to use event then you can do it with an other interface to receive the commands.

When creating a CommandBase you pass the instance of your class as parameter. When the CommandBase receive a command, it will call that instance.

```
MustInherit Class BaseClass
    Inherits RibbonTextBox
    Implements ICommandAction

    Sub New()
        Me.Commandhandler = New CommandBase(Me)
    End Sub

    Protected MustOverride Sub Execute(ByVal parameter As Object) Implements ICommandAction.Executecommand

End Class

Public Class CommandBase
    Implements ICommand

    Public Sub New(ByVal receiver As ICommandAction)
        _receiver = receiver
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Function CanExecute(ByVal parameter As Object) As Boolean Implements System.Windows.Input.ICommand.CanExecute
        Return Not parameter.value.ToString.IsEmptyStringOrNothing
    End Function

    Public Event CanExecuteChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Implements System.Windows.Input.ICommand.CanExecuteChanged

    Protected Overridable Sub Execute(ByVal parameter As Object) Implements System.Windows.Input.ICommand.Execute
        _receiver.Executecommand(parameter)
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class DerivedClass
    Inherits BaseClass

    Protected Overrides Sub Execute(ByVal parameter As Object)

    End Sub

End Class
```

Here's what ICommandAction could look like

```
Interface ICommandAction

    Sub Executecommand(ByVal parameter As Object)

End Interface
```

Comment: I can't find ICommandAction... What I'm missing... some reference I overseen? BR,Daniel

Comment: @dba it's a custom interface. I added a sample of what it could look like.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `Overridable` and `Overrides` modifiers, like [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/818x9db9%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). Also, you need to make sure that the base function is visible (`Public` or `Protected`) in the inherited `Class`. Finally, you need to make sure that you are using the right syntax:

```
Public Overrides Sub Execute()
'here the definition of commandexecution
End Sub
```

Comment: I think I am using overridable/overrides modifiers, my issue is, that I don't inherit this subclass directly, I'd need to Override a nested instance method in my derived class.... I do not derive the commandbase, but the Baseclass, where a Property has an Instance of the CommandBase

Comment: Inheritance works in a transitive way. If there is an Overridable Function at a class and it is either Protected or Public, then you can override it even in the class you inherit from the class inherited from the mentioned class.

Comment: I cannot confirm, that a nested overridable Function/Sub can be overridden in a derived class. Maybe when I declare a overrides overrideable in the direct parent (base).... I think I go with the_lotus'  solution. thanks anyway.